# How to get datatype in Julia

Tags: types, julia

If I want to get a vector's datatype. I used typeof(), and it returned 'Vector{Int64}'.
Is there any method that can just return 'Vector' not 'Vector{Int64}'?

Comment: `typeof(v).name.name` returns `:Array`. This is a symbol. Then `eval(typeof(v).name.name)` returns `Array`.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But is it possible to get 'Vector' not 'Array'?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't found. But once you get `Array` you can check it's a vector with `length(size(v))` or `isa(v, Vector)`.

Comment: Note that most likely you DON'T want to use this... rather you will leverage multiple dispatch to an arguments like `x::AbstractVector`

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the procedure you're asking for can go many directions. The concrete type `Vector{Int64}` is an alias for `Array{Int64,1}`. Because there are multiple parameters, there are multiple abstract `UnionAll` supertypes:

1. If you despecify the element type, you get `Vector`, aka `Array{T,1} where T`.
2. If you despecify the dimensions, you get `Array{Int64}`, aka `Array{Int64,N} where N`.
3. If you despecify all the parameters, you get `Array`.

There's no general reason to pick any one `UnionAll` over the others, it's a specific choice you have to make. And once you made that choice (`Vector`), there's no reason for a procedure to get to it, you can just check for it directly `my_object isa Vector`.

If you're working with a type that only has 1 parameter, you can just go for option 3 with `Ref{Int64}.name.wrapper` to get to the only `UnionAll` instance `Ref`.

Answer (score 0):

The element type is part of type definition.
Hence to get `Vector` alone this would need to be a one dimensional `Array` without type definition. Perhaps you could write something like this:

```
julia> a = [1,2];

julia> eval(nameof(typeof(a))){T,ndims(a)} where T
Vector (alias for Array{T, 1} where T)
```